# Стесняться кого-то или перед кем-то?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

Многие спрашивают о том, как перестать стесняться людей.
Что они имеют в виду, конечно, понятно всем, но разве правильным будет "не стесняться перед людьми"? А иначе кажется, будто ты этого человека не считаешь ровней, а общение с ним — просто стыд.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Вот что говорится в толковом словаре Дмитриева:
[стесня́ться](https://gufo.me/dict/dmitriev/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F#:%7E:text=1.,%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%85%2C%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9.) (глаг., нсв., употр. сравн. часто)
**1.** Когда кто-либо **стесняется**, он испытывает чувство неловкости в общении с кем-либо. *Стесняться взрослых, детей.* | ***Стесняться перед девушками.*** | *св. Постесняться чьего-либо присутствия.*
**= робе́ть**

Думаю, что в таком значении возможно управление *перед кем* (встречается нечасто).

*Разговор не клеился, офицеры **стеснялись перед** полковыми **дамами** и не могли взять верного тона, дамы нервно смеялись* (П. Н. Краснов (1922)).

*Никогда раньше он не видел у отца этой хитрой и подленькой улыбки. Отец **не стеснялся перед сыном*** (А. К. Виноградов (1936)).

Answer (score 0):

Словарь «Пунктуация и управление в русском языке» Д. Э. Розенталя и многие авторы с вами не согласны.

> **стесняться**
>
> кого-чего (разг. кого — вин. пад.), (устар. кем-чем), с кем, в чем.
>
> 1. кого-чего, кем-чем (испытывать чувство неловкости, застенчивости, смущения). Сначала он стеснялся Екатерины Михайловны, но потом, видя ее дружеское отношение, освоился (Н. Островский). Володя... ужасно стеснялся отца и мать (Шугаев). [Главный врач] любил отпускать двусмысленные шутки, не стесняясь присутствия женщин (Симонов).
> 2. с кем и в чём (действовать беззастенчиво, не церемониться — с отрицанием «не»). Вы можете сейчас же нас выгнать вон... Не стесняйтесь с нами (А. Н. Островский). Не стесняться в выражениях.
>
> https://upravlenie.academic.ru/2271/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F

Comment: Но ведь многие авторы считают выражение "стесняться перед [кем-то [чего-то] ]"вполне допустимым. Приведу несколько фамилий для примера: Виноградов, Залыгин, Искандер, Куприн, Ленин, Леонов, Мамин-Сибиряк, Панова, Солженицын.

Comment: @grizzly Да, часто можно услышать что-то типа "*он ни перед кем не стесняется так себя вести*", а здесь *кого-чего* не подходит.